# Describing Oracle Schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having a huge Oracle database with multiple schema's in it.

i want to describe the entire schema (one schema at a time) with all the tabel's in that schema and the structure of those table i.e. column name , datatype.

how can i do this task using SqlDeveloper ?

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Oracle's views:

all_tables,
all_tab_columns

Comment: can you write one example query

Comment: select * from all_tables. If you use sqldeveloper it will show you the columns the view contains neatly next to each other. Same for all_tab_columns. You can join the two views by owner and table_name.